# Can I transform a user-id to PSID? - Facebook API Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

**Context**: I'm building a webhook with NodeJS to get events from Facebook Page with my Facebook App. These events are: **feed**, **mention** (when a user tags the page on his wall) and **message**. I can get all events without problem. In all events I need to identify the user who write. When the users write a post or message in the page I get an ID (**PSID**) but when the user write a post on his wall tagging the page I can't get **PSID**, this is obvious because he isn't in the page scope. The only I get from this event is **user-id** from **post-id**.

I have tried the following:

- I used this endpoint `GET: /<user-id>/ids_for_pages` as indicated in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching). This doesn't work for me because I would need that the pages are in my business administrator and this isn't possible because I need this webhook to manage many pages to many companies.
- I used this endpoint `GET: /<psid>?fields=name,id` for events of type feed and messages (from Messenger) into the page but this gives me only PSID again.

*Note*: In my DB I save long-lived token of my page, ASID of the site owner and Page ID when my user does the login in the UI.

My questions:

- **Is possible transform user-id to PSID?**
- **Can I get user-id through the PSID?**

If you have a better idea to unify IDs when is the same user, I would like to know it. If this isn't possible I would also like know it.

**My Goal**: Each user event goes to the same case for the same user in my API, for this reason if the user is the same when tags the page and/or write a message in the page the idea is to identify him like same user and not like new case.

Comment: Why do you need to know the users PSID?

Comment: @WizKid I need the users PSID because these are my unique identifier to recognize to a client. If a user writes a publication in the page and the same user tags this page in his wall then I need to identify like same user but in both cases the ID are differents.

Comment: Why do you need to identify that they are the same? Maybe what you trying to do you can do in a different way if you explain what your high level goal is

Comment: @WizKid My goal is that each user that generates an event either by sending message or by tagging the page goes to the same case for that user. So in this moment my API when receive a new ID this create a new case in my inbox because the only reliable identifier is the sender_id or PSID but when a user tags the page this is different ID. I can edit my ask with the high level goal... Thanks for your interest!